# Usage of rightscale init script in it's EC2 Centos 5.4 AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos5, amazon-ami, rightscale

I was searching for EC2 EBS storage Centos 5.4 AMI in the community AMI and eventually I found Rightscale AMI (I think they called it RightImage).

Now I have created instance using that AMI, but I found out there is some Rightscale stuff inside which is worrying me about the safety on using it. I found out there are the following files in that AMI:
/etc/init.d/rightimage
/etc/init.d/rightlink
/etc/init.d/rightscale
/home/ec2
/home/s3sync
(may be more other files I haven't found out yet)

I know I can look into the script and folder and see what they do, but since a lot of user here recommended using Rightscale Centos AMI in EC2, I hope may be there is already some gurus here know what those mentioned script and folder doing and could advice me
i)whether is it safe to delete them. (I'm more concern on whether my data in the server will be safe by using this AMI)
ii)any installed apps in RightScale AMI that should be deleted

And if you think there is other free EC2 Centos AMI that is secure and solid, do suggest as well, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for RightScale to properly manage instances in ec2 they use a ruby based daemon called RightLink as a communication device between their core platform and each instance that is launched.  The init scripts that you saw are required for the instance to self configure itself to the point where it can be managed by RightScale properly.

/etc/init.d/rightimage is the first script that is run.  Essentially it just determines the OS, arch version, and installs the correct RightLink package from the S3 bucket.  Afterwards it kicks off the /opt/rightscale/bin/post_install.sh script which uses the OS init control tools to register the startup scripts to be invoked on future boots of the OS; this ensures that RightLink will always be started.

/etc/init.d/rightscale is the next script that is run.  It initializes RightScale-specific (but not RightLink-specific) system state. It is responsible for caching launch settings (aka userdata) and metadata in /var/spool and installing any available patches to the RightLink agent.

/etc/init.d/rightlink is the final script that is run.  It configures and enrolls the RightLink agent idempotently. If configuration and enrollment succeed, rightlink starts the sandboxed monit which starts the persistent agent process.  If you're not launching the AMI using the RightScale platform this will never properly enroll because they aren't expecting it to, as such RightScale will have no communication with the instance at all.

Removing all three of these from the image shouldn't in any way harm the overall stability of the image, but from a security standpoint they shouldn't cause any problems if they are present.

If you have any further specific questions about it I'd suggest hopping on their forums at https://forums.rightscale.com/

You could also try #rightscale on freenode.

Comment: Thanks!Appreciated so much for the answer!Can I also delete /etc/rightscale.d and /home/ec2 and /home/s3sync and the user 'rightscale' from the system?